# Trello hotkey to turn a text to hyperlink NOT via markdown?

Tags: trello, keyboard-shortcuts, links

Using the [markdown](http://help.trello.com/article/821-using-markdown-in-trello) seems to slow me down a lot.

I love the way we can turn text to link via `Ctrl+L` overhere on **stackexchange** pages.

In Trello, I'm looking for a shortcut/hotkey to do so; though seem not possible via [a Google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?newwindow=1&biw=1837&bih=966&noj=1&q=trello%20hotkey%20to%20turn%20a%20text%20to%20hyperlink%20NOT%20via%20markdown&oq=trello%20hotkey%20to%20turn%20a%20text%20to%20hyperlink%20NOT%20via%20markdown&gs_l=serp.3...91776.97024.0.97168.17.17.0.0.0.0.154.1778.7j9.16.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.5.604...33i21._WZpQyQPNZw).

Comment: I made a Trello extension for detecting URL's on the front of Trello cards, but it doesn't use `markdown`. I plan to extend it in the future when I get some time. [GTD: Trello Card Links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gtd-trello-card-links/kpbpniempdinfjfgphomcfkijinlgfgj)